# How to share audio file to multiple apps

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser, share-intent

```
String sharePath = dataSavingModels.get(pos).getPathOfRecording();

Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dataSavingModels.get(pos).getTextSaved());
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

This is the code that I am using to send an audio file, it only sends audio files to WhatsApp, and no other app like Messenger, or Telegram or KakaoTalk

Comment: What exactly is the value of `sharePath`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create our own class inheriting `FileProvider` in order to make sure our FileProvider doesn't conflict with FileProviders declared in imported dependencies. First create class with name `GenericFileProvider` like this:

```
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

public class GenericFileProvider extends FileProvider {
}
```

Then create `provider_paths.xml` inside `res/xml` folder. Folder may be needed to created if it doesn't exist. The content of the file is shown below. It describes that we would like to share access to the External Storage at root folder `(path=".")` with the name **external_files**.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Now in manifest inside `application` tag, add this lines:

```
       <provider
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.my.package.name.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

Then Try this code:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("audio/*");
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".my.package.name.provider", new File(Objects.requireNonNull(sharePath))));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```